# What tool for managing Oracle DB do you suggest?

Tags: sql, database

What tool for managing Oracle DB do you suggest? I need to execute scripts and manage data in tables and develop some scripts and packages. I'v tried SQL developer and actually don't like it. Want some more features for developing (debug, code assist, integrated help and so on.)

Comment: What don't you like about SQL developer?

Comment: It took me awhile to like sql developer, but the more I used it, the more I liked it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature wise, I would use Toad or SQL Navigator. Although I think for the little they are offering they are horrible expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Surprising i haven't seen a message about Toad for Oracle. Its the best I've worked with so far.
http://www.toadsoft.com/toad_oracle.htm

Comment: Heard about it. Think it is too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out about this today and it looks impressive: http://www.dbvis.com/

I've never used this before but have you looked at http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/ (although it doesn't seem as full featured as SQL Developer)

Answer (score 1):

Back in my Oracle days, I always liked to use the [Benthic Software Golden Tools](https://www.benthicsoftware.com/index.html) - extremely lightweight, useful, intuitive to use, inexpensive to license - great stuff all around!

Benthic also offer a PLEdit tool to edit PL/SQL code, and a GoldLoad tool to batch load large amounts of data into Oracle.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll look through it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/) from Allround Automations for the last several years.  Very solid.  Toad is great if your budget can afford it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should take a look at [Devart's OraDeveloper Studio](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio). It is a powerful development environment for working with Oracle, that provides an easier way to develop SQL scripts and PL/SQL program units, create and execute queries, manage users and privileges, explore existing databases, modify schema objects, export and import data, create database projects, and more.

[image]